# How to use Microsoft converters

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

I have found reach set of converters in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.Converters, but i don't know how to use them in xaml. Particularly, i don't how to include this namespace into xaml. Maybe it is only allowed to use it in code?

[List of converters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.controls.wpf.converters(v=vs.110).aspx)

I tried

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.Converters;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls"
```

and then

```
<conv:NullToVisibleConverter x:Key="Null2VisConv"/>
```

but it can't find `NullToVisibleConverter` in `conv.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft WPF converters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573895/microsoft-wpf-converters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to target .NET 4.5, then add reference to `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls` (should be in Assembilies -> Extensions) and then in XAML, as you did

```xml
<Window ...
        xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.Converters;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls">
    <Window.Resources>
        <conv:NullToVisibleConverter x:Key="Null2VisConv"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <!-- ... -->
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that have these pkgs installed.
You must add reference  to dll in your project.

MSDN says:
You can find the assemblies in the client object model in Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE under ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0, ReferenceAssemblies\v4.5, and PrivateAssemblies.

After thar you write in your xaml for example:

```
xmlns:converters="namespace for converters"
```

you can choose namespace for converters from the list of namespace you have on your pc